# Flash Actionscript 3.0 Loading screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loading, preloader, scene

I'm trying to get a loading screen to work in Flash.  This is how my project is set up:

- All of the game occurs in "Layer 1," which is set up into many different scenes: "Level 0," "Level 1," etc.  Its code is run in a ".as" file
- I tried implementing a simple loading screen (with a progress bar) in a new layer, "Preloader."  Its code is run in the layer's "Actions."

I realize that putting the Preloader's code in its "Actions" wasn't the best idea because I had Layer 1's ".as" file load Level 0 at first.  So the "Preloader" and "Layer 1" layers tried to run at the same time.  This caused problems.

Now I have tried putting the Preloader into a scene of its own.  That is not working.

Here is the code I've tried using for the Preloader - "scene" version:

```
        // This function loads the Preloader
    public function loadPL(event:Event) {
        // Load the Scene associated with the Preloader
        this.gotoAndStop(1, "PL");


        // Prevent the MovieClip (game) from playing right away
        stop();

        // Add an EventListener that calls the 'loading()' function
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingPL);


    } // End of 'loadPL()' method               

        // 'loading()' function
            // This function calculates how much of the game has been loaded vs. how much data
            // the game contains. The loading progress bar is resized accordingly.
        public function loadingPL(e:Event):void{
            // How much data does the game have in all?
            var totalData:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;

            // How much data has been loaded so far?
            var loadedData:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

            // Scale the 'plBarIns' according to the loadedData:totalData ratio
            plBarIns.scaleX = loadedData/totalData;

            // If the 'loadedData' == 'totalData' (all of the game's data has been loaded), allow
                // the game to play
            if (loadedData == totalData) {
                play();

                // Remove the EventListener that calls the 'loading()' function. It's not needed now
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingPL);
            }
        }
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your preloader in frame 1 and have the rest of your project start on frame 2. After that you need to setup your ActionScript settings so it knows to load all of your classes on frame 2 instead of frame 1.

Here's what settings you need to change:

1. File > ActionScript Settings...
2. Change "Export classes in frame:" to 2
3. Change "Default linkage:" to Merged into code

Your loaderinfo should now return the proper progress of the file loading instead of instantly jumping to completed.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  However, I have tried another method.  As I mentioned in my previous post, each level in my game is a different Scene. So each level uses the first frame of its respective Scene. I have tried putting the Preloader in a Scene of its own.  When the game starts, the Preloader scene is supposed to load.  Then after the game's loaded, Level 1 is supposed to start. That did not work. Should I put all the different levels into Frames instead of Scenes? Or is there a way to implement a Preloader with Scenes?

Comment: Also, you may want to instantiate your main document class via getDefinitionByName on frame 2, since dragging an actual instance on frame 2 will cause a variable of type "YourDocumentClass" to be created on the main timeline, which seems to force it to be exported in frame 1.